# Associate controller to a view if the controller exists using emberjs

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-app-kit

I'd like to know if there is a way to check if a controller exists using Ember, then associate it to a view?

I'm going through a list of element coming from an array, and depending of those element, I generate a view, and sometimes I need to associate a controller to this view. I'm using Ember AppKit.

```
export default Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    init: function () {
        this._super();

        var self = this;
        myList = [{name: 'element-1'}, {name: 'element-2'}];

        myList.forEach(function (element) {
            self.push(Ember.View.create({
                templateName: 'path/to/template/'+element.name,
                controller: 'path/to/controller/'+element.name //Associate the controller only if it exists, I don't know how to do that.
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Views will use the current controller. see http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_general.
Your best bet would be using a Helper, It's further discussed here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/dynamically-render-polymorphic-component/3184

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment of your question, the `View` knows its `Controller` so I'd go the other way and tell the `Controller` beforehand which other controllers are needed through its `needs` property which could then be aliased and observed by the view.